# Find field in Ext.panel.Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs6

In `Ext.form.Panel` we can find all fields like this: `form.findField('field_name')`

Is there a simple way to find fields in `Ext.panel.Panel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to find fields in Ext.panel.Panel?

Yes in [panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html) or any other component (only which component that contain some items) you can find component using different way.

**1.**  Using [down()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#method-down) retrieves the first descendant of this container which matches the passed selector.

**2.** Using [getComponent()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#method-getComponent) attempts a default component lookup. If the component is not found in the normal items, the dockedItems are searched and the matched component (if any) returned.

**3.** Using [Ext.ComponentQuery.query](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html) provides searching of Components within Ext.ComponentManager (globally) or a specific Ext.container.Container on the document with a similar syntax to a CSS selector. Returns Array of matching Components, or empty Array.

> Here I have created an [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/295b) demo you can check here how it is working.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    bodyPadding: 5, // Don't want content to crunch against the borders
    width: '100%',
    title: 'Find Components',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'fullname',
        itemId: 'fullname',
        fieldLabel: 'Name'
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        name: 'dob',
        itemId: 'dob',
        fieldLabel: 'Date Of Birth'
    }, {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        name: 'state',
        itemId: 'state',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
            data: [{
                "abbr": "AL",
                "name": "Alabama"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AK",
                "name": "Alaska"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AZ",
                "name": "Arizona"
            }]
        }),
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        queryMode: 'local',
        valueField: 'abbr'
    }, {
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        name: 'mobile',
        itemId: 'mobile',
        fieldLabel: 'Mobile Number'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        name: 'feedback',
        itemId: 'feedback',
        fieldLabel: 'Feedback'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Get All Component',
        handler: function () {
            this.up('panel').doGetAllComponent(['dob','fullname','state','feedback','mobile']);
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    doGetAllComponent: function (data) {
        var panel = this;
        data.map(function (value) {
            console.log('find component using name config');
            console.log(panel.down('[name=' + value + ']'));
            console.log('find component using itemId');
            console.log(panel.down('#' + value));
            console.log('find component using getComponent ');
            console.log(panel.getComponent(value));
            console.log('find component using Ext.ComponentQuery.query()');
            console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#' + value)[0]);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query();` is your friend here. Basically this function allows you to search for any ext element in your application using jquery-esque selectors.
See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html

Another option would be to use the down() function to search children of an object or up() to search for ancestors.
i.e.: `panel.down('field')` yields all field xtype elements that are descendants (on any level) of whatever is in the panel variable.
Note: Not all Ext elements have up and down methods. In that case you can still use the componentquery and denote a hierarchy in the selector part.

Comment: Containers have methods to query children. Components only have methods to query above themselves.

Comment: Thanks for that addition. I didn't really know the mechanics behind that as you can see. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ext.ComponentQuery, up/Down, Ext.get() normally it will impact the performance of your application. You can test the behaviour of component pull using timer function. My advise is better go for **naming** **reference**.

**View**

```
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    name: 'mobile',
    itemId: 'numMobileId',
    fieldLabel: 'Mobile Number'
},
```

**Controller :**

```
refs:{
  'numMobileId' : 'PersonalInfo [itemId='numMobileId']';
}
```

Comment: This is just wrong, it's not going to have any measurable impact on performance. If you want to use named references, then the `reference` should be used on the component and `lookupReference` should be called from the controller.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Please read my answer twice. and try to execute in code you get the difference of it. I had took performance measure's in Extjs6 going with name reference with be better when compare to all

Comment: I said a measurable difference, unless you're executing this code lots of times a second it's not going to matter.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I have tested clearing cache too. I got same report. So only i'm 100% sure on component usage.

Comment: I don't really know what you're talking about. It won't make a measurable difference in a real world app.